# Java - Nested loops - Having trouble getting any output

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I came up with this idea to simulate the way a plant grows. The idea is based off of fractal geometry and basically how that explains the repetitions of branches and other structures in plants. I am very much a beginner with programming, though, so I thought I'd test out JUST the basic logic of repeating something. Below is what I wrote in Java.

```
/*
Java program:   plant.java

This program runs a loop simulating plant growth.
The idea is that the plant will continue to have "repeated"
growth and that it will stop (or slow down to a crawl) at some point, 
in this case at 100 branches.

*/

public class plant
{
    public static void main (String [] poop)
    {
        int current_growth = 0, limit = 100; //plant growth starts at ZERO and is limited to 100
        String word = "branches";

        while (current_growth > 0)
        {
            //here, we are checking to see if the plant has grown just 1 inch.
            //this is important just for grammatical purposes
            if (current_growth == 1)
            {
                word = "branch"; //this changes the "word" to branch instead of branches
            }


        System.out.println("Your plant has grown " + current_growth + " " + word);
        //if you put the singular count check here, it doesn't work at all
        current_growth = current_growth + 1;

            if (current_growth > 0)
            {
            System.out.println("Your plant has grown " + current_growth + " " + word);
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.println("Your plant will no longer grow.");
            } // end else
        } //end while loop
    } //end main method
} //end class
```

I did the following:

1. Saved it in my Java depository Changed my depository to point to
   there
2. Called/compiled the code with `MacBook-Air:Java bdeely$ javac plant.java`
3. Ran the code with `MacBook-Air:Java bdeely$ java plant`

The problem was that:
- There was no output at all. The command prompt just went back empty like `MacBook-Air:Java bdeely$`

I'm fairly certain I am making some kind of huge rookie mistake here. Does anyone know how I can get this code to give me output that repeats the loop from 0 up to 100?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your `while` loop condition. It won't be true, and hence the execution doesn't enter it.

Answer (score 1):

Edited :

```
 public class plant
    {
        public static void main (String [] poop)
        {
            int current_growth = 0, limit = 1;//set limit to 1 //plant growth starts at ZERO and is limited to 100
        String word = "branches";

    while (limit<=100)// for 100 iterations limit
    {
        //here, we are checking to see if the plant has grown just 1 inch.
        //this is important just for grammatical purposes
        if (current_growth == 1)
        {
            word = "branch"; //this changes the "word" to branch instead of branches
        }


    System.out.println("Your plant has grown " + current_growth + " " + word);
    //if you put the singular count check here, it doesn't work at all
    current_growth = current_growth + 1;

        if (current_growth > 0)
        {
        System.out.println("Your plant has grown " + current_growth + " " + word);
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Your plant will no longer grow.");
        } // end else
       limit=limit+1;// increment
    } //end while loop
} //end main method
} //end class
```

Comment: you can use and enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `current_growth` is initialized to `0`

```
while (current_growth > 0) // never becomes true
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because at start your `current_growth = 0` but while condition is `(current_growth > 0)`
Why don't you use `for` loop:

```
for(current_growth = 0; current_growth < limit; ++current_growth)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method. I'm going to go with the for loop

Answer (score 0):

your `current_growth` is 0. make it `>= 0` in the while